# multiple ports being used in UDP transport of RTI connext DDS?

Tags: linux, tcp, udp, data-distribution-service, opendds

What is the advantage of having multiple ports being used in UDP transport of RTI connext DDS whereas only one port is being used in TCP/IP of RTI connext DDS??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UDP port mapping is defined by the *OMG RTPS DDS Interoperability Wire Protocol Specification* (http://www.omg.org/spec/DDSI-RTPS/), *Platform Specific Model (PSM) : UDP/IP*.

There are a few advantages/requirements that justify using different ports for discovery and data traffic. The most relevant ones are:

- **Traffic differentiation**: using different ports makes easier to
  identify different kinds of traffic. This is useful for both
  debugging (e.g., using wireshark), and for applying a different
  treatment to discovery and user data traffic.
- **Parallelism**: by using multiple ports it is possible to parallelize
  the processing and generation of discovery and user data traffic.
  This is critical in some environments that have strict latency
  requirements for the user data traffic.

*RTI Connext TCP Transport* design meets those two requirements, but it has an additional requirement:

- **NAT support**: TCP Transport should be easy to configure in NAT
  environments.

*RTI Connext TCP Transport* supports a mode where it opens only one server port for accepting all the connections (on the configured server_bind_port) needed for communicating two Participants. This way, it is compatible with NAT environments where only the Participant running the *RTI TCP* server has a publicly reachable address and port. Then, the Participants running *RTI TCP* clients will just open connections to that server.

Note that even if *RTI TCP Transport* opens just one server port/socket, the server only uses that socket for accepting connections. *RTI TCP Transport* is still opening a different connection for handling each traffic kind and direction (incoming/outcoming discovery, incoming/outcoming user data). Parallelism requirement is still met.

About traffic differentiation, *RTI TCP Transport* adds additional headers to the RTPS traffic, so it can be easily identified on the wire.

Note this is specific to *RTI*, as currently there is no specification for an *OMG TCP PSM model*, nonetheless it is currently on the works by the *OMG*.

Comment: Thanx a lot...By the way I am new to RTI's OMG DDS middleware standards.Can you please explain me what is the difference between user meta data and discovery meta data?

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the questions about "advantage".  I can explain why it is done that way, however, and so you can make your own judgements.

The UDP anonymous, peer-to-peer discovery methodology is defined in the standard that way.  The standard defines how port numbers are arrived at for a given Participant, on a given address.  Because it is in the standard, then Vendor-A's DDS can find Vendor-B's DDS immediately.

There is no comparable TCP-analog to the UDP defined standard.  Eventually there will be, but at the moment, each vendor who desires to provide a TCP transport, is free to do it however they want.  This means that for the most part, Vendor-A's method will not work with Vendor-B's method, so they will not see each other.

By the way, this is why shared memory transports are also not vendor-interoperable.

RTI Connext TCP/IP transport uses a single port for *discovery*.  After that, it uses whichever ephemeral ports get created for the socket connections between the peers.